# How to use Item value inside Foreach of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have "Foreach" with Items: @activity('Fetch').output.value.
It includes list of CustomerName like Tesla.

I have "Lookup" inside ForEach.
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName='@item().CustomerName'

This gives SQL errors since it passes directly string '@item().CustomerName' instead of feeding actual value.  Please advice correct syntax.

How to use item value inside Foreach of Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 3):

When working with ADF expressions, you should wrap your parameters or variables with curly brackets.

For OP's case, it would be
`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName='@{item().CustomerName}'`

Answer (score 1):

Try using expression like this

```
@concat('select * from customers where customername=''',item().name,'''')
```

this will pass query like

```
select * from customers where customername='tesla'
```