# Azure Data Factory use result of a Lookup for iterating in a ForEach

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a Lookup that gives as a result a column with 200 results. Then i need to use each row in another pipeline, using a ForEach.
I've tried `@activity(Lookup1).output.value` but It does not seem to work.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share an example of your data ? i dont quite understand what do you want to do with the values , do you want to send each value to another pipeline ? can you please share your pipeline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the output of `Lookup` activity with `ForEach` loop where both Lookup activity and Foreach activity are present in the same pipeline, then `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` will work. But if Lookup activity is in one pipeline and you want to pass this result to ForEach activity in another pipeline, you need to follow a different approach.

**Look at the following demonstration (Both activity in same pipeline):**

- The following `Lookup` activity selects 10 rows of a single column in my table.

[image]

- In `ForEach` activity, I have given the value `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` for items.

[image]

- Inside foreach I have used `script` activity to insert values into a table. The pipeline runs successfully and inserts values into my target table.

[image]

**When Lookup is in one pipeline and for each in another:**

- Let's say `lookup_pipeline` pipeline has lookup activity (selects 10 rows of a table column) and `execute_pipeline` pipeline has foreach activity.
- In the foreach activity, create a parameter called `values` of `object` type.

[image]

- Now go back to `lookup_pipeline` and create an `execute pipeline` activity. Select invoked pipeline as `execute_pipeline`. Once you do this, the parameter `values` appears below and you can specify its value (`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`) here.

[image]

- Now open the foreach activity in `execute_pipeline` and give the value for items as `@pipeline().parameters.values`

[image]

- I used the same script activity inside foreach activity. Now run the `lookup_pipeline`, it successfully runs and gives the output.

[image]

**Note:**

- If you want to pass only the row value to another pipeline (pipeline2) but not entire lookup activity output object, follow the approach used in above method.
- You can use `lookup` and `foreach` in same pipeline(pipeline1), create `execute pipeline` activity inside `foreach` activity and pass the row value as `@item()` (another pipeline 'pipeline2' must have parameter of required type to get row value passed from 'pipeline1').

Comment: '@item().ProductId' does not work, i found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850674/how-to-use-item-value-inside-foreach-of-azure-data-factory that '{@item().ProductId}' works instead

Comment: Yes @DuccioBorchi, that is correct. I have used `@{item().ProductID}` instead, which also works (can be seen in the `script` activity image).